# Tortoise SVN update doesn't restore a deleted working copy

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Accidentally I deleted a working copy folder in my local repo. Is there a way to get it back ? SVN update is not helping me. When I Update it shows success. But no files/folders will be created. I did not do a SVN delete. I deleted the folder from file system. Can anyone please help ?

Comment: You need to use "revert" in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the problem and solution. Seems like SVN maintains a file in which it has remembered status of each working copy. Now when you delete any version'ed file, SVN doesn't know of this. Hence when you try update, it does nothing.

**Solution:** 
Solution is to right click on the parent folder and try to update it to any revision which is not latest. When you do this, the folder goes into conflict state as it does not find the files. Once in conflict, resolve the conflict and do an update to revision which you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you had local changes in the folder, they're lost unless you recover them from the recycle bin, of course. If your working copy was under a parent directory that's also under version control (A `Projects` or `Source Code` directory, for example), you can simply do a revert on that directory to get your local copy back, without local modifications.

If your directory was the top-most local directory, that is: its parent directory is not under version control, you'll have to do a fresh checkout of the directory to get it back.